# Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
     Date mydate = new Date();
     java.util.Calendar cd = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
     int dc = cd.get(1);

     Year.setText("Today : "+mydate.getDate() + ":" + mydate.getMonth() + ":" + dc);
     ActionListener actiondate = null;

     new javax.swing.Timer(1000, actiondate).start();
     return;
}
```

When I Complie my program with this code I get the above error.

Comment: From which package is the `Year` class in the above code?  Are you certain that this method is what is causing the compiler error/warning?  What about the rest of your code?

Comment: java.util.Calendar.getInstance

Comment: I see no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning comes from this line

```
Year.setText("Today : "+mydate.getDate() + ":" + mydate.getMonth() + ":" + dc);
```

From the [Javadoc of Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) you can see that the methods `getDyate()` and `getMonth()` (and other methods) are deprecated.